# Need help resolving segfault in libc-2.23.so

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, gdb, glibc

Need help debugging shared library with gdb.

I am trying to debug a shared library and in my case it is:
*libc-2.23.so*

The reason is that I get theese lines in dmesg:

```
[10081.433266] compiz[11346]: segfault at 7f30a4100010 ip 00007f309c36f44b sp 00007ffdde303aa0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f309c2f1000+1bf000]
[22005.764635] compiz[16149]: segfault at 7f30e3456db0 ip 00007f30db85044b sp 00007fffaab9c0a0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f30db7d2000+1bf000]
[48777.031064] compiz[25203]: segfault at 7f0b8e23b050 ip 00007f0b87edf44b sp 00007ffd51d15740 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f0b87e61000+1bf000]
[78850.413793] compiz[4889]: segfault at 7f60ddbf2440 ip 00007f60d598944b sp 00007ffedc5e31b0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f60d590b000+1bf000]
[84583.754783] compiz[8441]: segfault at 7f5f8c3930c0 ip 00007f5f871d544b sp 00007ffc436bb5a0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f5f87157000+1bf000]
[100625.457854] compiz[15619]: segfault at 7ffffa967680 ip 00007ffff722844b sp 00007fffffffdad0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ffff71aa000+1bf000]
[104234.596331] compiz[19076]: segfault at 7ffffa2dc540 ip 00007ffff722844b sp 00007fffffffd810 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ffff71aa000+1bf000]
[112314.238115] compiz[22152]: segfault at 7ffffe232760 ip 00007ffff722844b sp 00007fffffffd810 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ffff71aa000+1bf000]
[130828.195732] compiz[26013]: segfault at 7ffffa966180 ip 00007ffff722844b sp 00007fffffffdad0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ffff71aa000+1bf000]
[225379.026592] compiz[19275]: segfault at 7ffff821b6d0 ip 00007ffff722844b sp 00007fffffffd7c0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7ffff71aa000+1bf000]
```

The address where libc-2.23.so is loaded does not change after time stamp 100625.457854 since I ran the command:

> $ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

In order to be able to load it under gdb.

What I have done so far is that I have established that the segfault always occur on the same offset from the shared librarys loaded address.
I calculated the offset by taking instruction pointer minus load address in python:

```
ld = ["7f309c2f1000", "7f30db7d2000", "7f0b87e61000", "7f60d590b000", "7f5f87157000", "7ffff71aa000"]
ip = ["7f309c36f44b", "7f30db85044b", "7f0b87edf44b", "7f60d598944b", "7f5f871d544b", "7ffff722844b"]
ld_val = [int(x,16) for x in ld]
ip_val=[int(x,16) for x in ip]
ip_off=[i-s for (i,s) in zip(ip_val,ld_val)]
ip_off
[517195, 517195, 517195, 517195, 517195, 517195]
```

So using this information I got the offending line from executing:

> $ addr2line -e /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so -fCi 0x7e44b
>   malloc_consolidate
>   /build/glibc-9tT8Do/glibc-2.23/malloc/malloc.c:4167

Since I run Ubuntu 16.04 I installed the sources by issuing:

> $ apt-get source glibc-source

Inspecting the offending line showed that it was just a comment.
malloc.c:4167

> ```
> /* Slightly streamlined version of consolidation code in free() */
> ```

inside function:

```
static void malloc_consolidate(mstate av)
```

So I am assuming I am doing something wrong here.
Any pointer on how to capture this "segfault"?

Comment: What I would like to see is the output after doing `catch throw` (catch the exception) then `backtrace` (display the call stack). This will give us a trace of where the problem is coming from as it is much more likely in your  own code, not in `glibc`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but *compiz* is not my code and even if it was I still would need to know where to put the **catch  throw** code.

Comment: Both these commands are for `gdb` before executing the program; if the problem is in `compiz`, file a bug with the maintainers. BTW, [this might be one area to investigate](https://askubuntu.com/q/688959/189361).

Comment: I followed instructions on the post to investigate but am still stuck with apport-retrace could not find public key for compiz_0.9.12.2+16.04.20160823-0ubuntu1.dsc.   
Will continue because it should be possible.

Comment: Were there any warning messages when you ran `apt-get source  glibc-source`? I just ran it, and line 4167 of malloc.c is `nextsize = chunksize(nextchunk);`. The comment in your line 4167 is in my line 4164. This could be explained by your `apt-get source` not having applied the `debian/patches/git-updates.diff` patch, which deletes a few lines around line 1074.

Comment: I just performed the command again and nothing more than gpgv problem with not finding public key and that it selected "glibc" as source packet instead of "glibc-source". It also reccomends to do a git clone: `git clone https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-glibc/glibc.git` which I did but I did not find any source files in the repo. Anyway, so you think there is a mismatch between the malloc.c from `apt-get source glibc-source` and my `libc-2.23.so`?

Comment: The `git` message is just there in case you want to get newer sources than what Ubuntu offers, and the `gpgv` message isn't really important if you got the files from an official repo with a reliable Internet connection. But just after that gpgv message, do you see `dpkg-source: info: unpacking glibc_2.23-0ubuntu7.debian.tar.xz` followed by `dpkg-source: info: applying git-updates.diff` ?

Comment: I see following: `dpkg-source: info: packar upp glibc_2.23-0ubuntu7.debian.tar.xz` followed by `dpkg-source: info: tillämpar git-updates.diff` so yes it does look the same. How come the `./malloc/malloc.c` differs? My sha256sum on it is: `232551177cf27c79f1fe2dab3f2086424ae35a3120bcdb02aa3956507df73658`and there is another malloc.c in folder `./.pc/git-updates.diff/malloc/malloc.c` which is different.

Comment: Mine has the same sha256 sum. `232551177cf27c79f1fe2dab3f2086424ae35a3120bcdb02aa3956507df73658  ./glibc-2.23/malloc/malloc.c` If you edit it and go to line 4167, don't you see `nextsize = chunksize(nextchunk);` ?

Comment: With ATOM editor I need to go to line 4169 but with gedit is it 4167.
I think we can close this discussion. I had gdb loaded with the library and breakpoint on line 4167 but no break even if I got a new entry in dmesg.

Answer (score 5):

> So I am assuming I am doing something wrong here.

You aren't.

The symptoms you are looking at are 99.999% result of heap corruption, and since this is happening in `compiz`, there is little you can do except file a bug report.

To make a useful bug report, it would help if you could run `compiz` under Valgrind. Running it under GDB will *not* help.

> I had gdb loaded with the library and breakpoint on line 4167 but no break even if I got a new entry in dmesg.

That means you are debugging the wrong process. Perhaps `compiz` forks helper processes, and one of them dies?